# Keeping a connection open for each client in php

Tags: php, sockets

I have a C++ backend application coded over a TCP socket, to which I connect PHP to. The problem is that the connection is closed on every refresh, change page, etc. I would like to keep the connection open for each client, doing something like $_Session does.

Comment: If we're talking about HTTP, the only thing that come close is [Keep-Alive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) which is of limited use and limited by server settings to certain maxes. It may prevent some overhead if the server supports it, but some reconnects over HTTP are inevitable, and I don't understand the connection with  `$_SESSION` (which does not keep on existing, but is recreated from a store on every request).

Answer (score 2):

This is not really what PHP (or the whole of web-based applications and services, for that matter) are meant for. It also means begging for resource problems before long because big PHP processes will be running simultaneously, instead of running for a quick moment on each request.

What speaks against making use of the normal session mechanisms from within your app (i.e. dealing with session ID cookies) like other clients?

I'm no expert in C++ but I'm sure that most http libraries can deal with a "cookie jar", which is essentially all you need to persist a session from within your client application.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know much about PHP, I can tell you that web browsers aren't designed to hold continuous connections. They have to reconnect every time they make a HTML request.

The HTTP standard specifies that the server will disconnect from the client after it has finished sending it it's request.

Comment: Change `HTML` to `HTTP` and you have a point (although a `TCP` socket may have nothing to do with `HTTP`, the OP speaking about 'refresh' & 'change page' heavily indicates it is)